# What is the C# equivalent of the MAKEWORD c++ Windows Macro?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I need to convert some c++ legacy code to C# and I was wondering what's the C# equivalent of the `MAKEWORD` c++ Windows Macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static uint MakeWord(byte low, byte high)
{
    return ((uint)high << 8) | low;
}
```

However, you might need the result as an `int` depending on what you're doing with it (cast if necessary).